# Installing QGIS plugin called profile from line?

Tags: qgis-plugins

i am trying to install a new plugin called profile from line and then this error appear and i dont konow what to do.

Couldn't load plugin 'profilefromline' from ['C:/Users/LOUREN~1/DOCUME~1/NEWFOL~1/Quantum GIS Lisboa/apps/qgis/./python', 'C:/Users/LourenÃ§o AmÃ©lia/.qgis//python', 'C:/Users/LourenÃ§o AmÃ©lia/.qgis//python/plugins', 'C:/Users/LOUREN~1/DOCUME~1/NEWFOL~1/Quantum GIS Lisboa/apps/qgis/./python/plugins', 'C:\Users\LOUREN~1\DOCUME~1\NEWFOL~1\Quantum GIS Lisboa\bin\python27.zip', 'C:\Users\LOUREN~1\DOCUME~1\NEWFOL~1\Quantum GIS Lisboa\apps\Python27\DLLs', 'C:\Users\LOUREN~1\DOCUME~1\NEWFOL~1\Quantum GIS Lisboa\apps\Python27\lib', 'C:\Users\LOUREN~1\DOCUME~1\NEWFOL~1\Quantum GIS Lisboa\apps\Python27\lib\plat-win', 'C:\Users\LOUREN~1\DOCUME~1\NEWFOL~1\Quantum GIS Lisboa\apps\Python27\lib\lib-tk', 'C:\Users\LOUREN~1\DOCUME~1\NEWFOL~1\Quantum GIS Lisboa\apps\qgis\bin', 'C:\Users\LOUREN~1\DOCUME~1\NEWFOL~1\Quantum GIS Lisboa\apps\Python27', 'C:\Users\LOUREN~1\DOCUME~1\NEWFOL~1\Quantum GIS Lisboa\apps\Python27\lib\site-packages', 'C:\Users\LOUREN~1\DOCUME~1\NEWFOL~1\Quantum GIS Lisboa\apps\Python27\lib\site-packages\PIL', 'C:\Users\LOUREN~1\DOCUME~1\NEWFOL~1\Quantum GIS Lisboa\apps\Python27\lib\site-packages\win32', 'C:\Users\LOUREN~1\DOCUME~1\NEWFOL~1\Quantum GIS Lisboa\apps\Python27\lib\site-packages\win32\lib', 'C:\Users\LOUREN~1\DOCUME~1\NEWFOL~1\Quantum GIS Lisboa\apps\Python27\lib\site-packages\Pythonwin', 'C:\Users\LOUREN~1\DOCUME~1\NEWFOL~1\Quantum GIS Lisboa\apps\Python27\lib\site-packages\wx-2.8-msw-unicode', 'C:\Users\LOUREN~1\DOCUME~1\NEWFOL~1\Quantum GIS Lisboa\apps\qgis\python\plugins\fTools\tools']

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/LOUREN~1/DOCUME~1/NEWFOL~1/Quantum GIS Lisboa/apps/qgis/./python\qgis\utils.py", line 143, in loadPlugin
    **import**(packageName)
  File "C:/Users/LOUREN~1/DOCUME~1/NEWFOL~1/Quantum GIS Lisboa/apps/qgis/./python\qgis\utils.py", line 309, in _import
    mod = _builtin_import(name, globals, locals, fromlist, level)
ImportError: No module named profilefromline

Python version:
2.7.2 (default, Jun 12 2011, 15:08:59) [MSC v.1500 32 bit (Intel)]

QGIS version:
1.8.0-Lisboa Lisboa, 6416f38

Python path: ['C:/Users/LOUREN~1/DOCUME~1/NEWFOL~1/Quantum GIS Lisboa/apps/qgis/./python', 'C:/Users/Louren\xc3\xa7o Am\xc3\xa9lia/.qgis//python', 'C:/Users/Louren\xc3\xa7o Am\xc3\xa9lia/.qgis//python/plugins', 'C:/Users/LOUREN~1/DOCUME~1/NEWFOL~1/Quantum GIS Lisboa/apps/qgis/./python/plugins', 'C:\Users\LOUREN~1\DOCUME~1\NEWFOL~1\Quantum GIS Lisboa\bin\python27.zip', 'C:\Users\LOUREN~1\DOCUME~1\NEWFOL~1\Quantum GIS Lisboa\apps\Python27\DLLs', 'C:\Users\LOUREN~1\DOCUME~1\NEWFOL~1\Quantum GIS Lisboa\apps\Python27\lib', 'C:\Users\LOUREN~1\DOCUME~1\NEWFOL~1\Quantum GIS Lisboa\apps\Python27\lib\plat-win', 'C:\Users\LOUREN~1\DOCUME~1\NEWFOL~1\Quantum GIS Lisboa\apps\Python27\lib\lib-tk', 'C:\Users\LOUREN~1\DOCUME~1\NEWFOL~1\Quantum GIS Lisboa\apps\qgis\bin', 'C:\Users\LOUREN~1\DOCUME~1\NEWFOL~1\Quantum GIS Lisboa\apps\Python27', 'C:\Users\LOUREN~1\DOCUME~1\NEWFOL~1\Quantum GIS Lisboa\apps\Python27\lib\site-packages', 'C:\Users\LOUREN~1\DOCUME~1\NEWFOL~1\Quantum GIS Lisboa\apps\Python27\lib\site-packages\PIL', 'C:\Users\LOUREN~1\DOCUME~1\NEWFOL~1\Quantum GIS Lisboa\apps\Python27\lib\site-packages\win32', 'C:\Users\LOUREN~1\DOCUME~1\NEWFOL~1\Quantum GIS Lisboa\apps\Python27\lib\site-packages\win32\lib', 'C:\Users\LOUREN~1\DOCUME~1\NEWFOL~1\Quantum GIS Lisboa\apps\Python27\lib\site-packages\Pythonwin', 'C:\Users\LOUREN~1\DOCUME~1\NEWFOL~1\Quantum GIS Lisboa\apps\Python27\lib\site-packages\wx-2.8-msw-unicode', 'C:\Users\LOUREN~1\DOCUME~1\NEWFOL~1\Quantum GIS Lisboa\apps\qgis\python\plugins\fTools\tools']

Answer (score 2):

`C:/Users/LourenÃ§o AmÃ©lia/.qgis//python`

The special characters in your user path are causing the issue. Change to a different user and the problem should vanish.